# Mongoose: populate all sub objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using a generic rest api that allow passing the mongo collection name on the request and serve it's content.

My LIST command looks like that:

```
router.get('/:collectionName', function(req, res, next) {
    req.collection.find().sort('-created_on').exec(function(e, results){
        if (e) return next(e);
        res.send(results)
    });
});
```

It works great.

My problem is that I want every list query to populate sub objects if exists.

I tried:

```
req.collection.find().populate().sort..
```

But obviously I get an error:

> TypeError: utils.populate: invalid path. Expected string. Got typeof `undefined`

Help?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but did you try to move your .populate() function after the .sort()? And have you tried it without .sort()?

Comment: I'm sorry for my late answer, but I see the mistake. .populate() will indeed only work with a query or the fields it should populate. I'm glad you have found the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I had to patch it:

```
router.get('/:collectionName', function(req, res, next) {
    var populationQuery = [];
    var paths = req.collection.schema.paths;
    for (var path in paths) {
        if (paths[path].caster) {
            populationQuery.push({path: path});
        }
    }
    req.collection.find().populate(populationQuery).sort('-created_on').exec(function (e, results) {
        if (e) return next(e);
        console.log(results);
        res.send(results)
    });
});
```

This works, but I guess there should be some better solution